# Is there an action to run convert require to import in vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, eslint

There is a quick fix action that converts require to import:

[image]

I would like to run it automatically on save from `editor.codeActionsOnSave`, or maybe there's an ESLint rule that has an auto fix?

P.S. I do not want to use vscode extensions for this.

Comment: I don't think there is a matching source action for the `Convert all 'require' to 'import'` fix.  If you check the context menu/Source Action...  there isn't one listed which is concerning.  And nothing looks promsing in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/a4597e19050ce5333e23c23c2493ddf38db0443d/extensions/typescript-language-features/package.nls.json